# Nativescript: issue to run app in android mobile

Tags: android, emulation, nativescript

I am trying to learn nativescript by following this doc - http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1
but getting issue with emulate/run app with device through USB
I am using ubuntu 16.4 & android 6.0
it show successful in terminal/console
but in mobile app display like this
[image]
can anyone help to resolve this issue 
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is problem with bindings so use this `tns platform remove android` and `tns platform add android@next` :)

**EDIT**

Or use tns run android before that

Comment: What helped then ? that `android@next`?